# Считывание данных из файла .csv

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, помогите с решением.
Не получается считать данные из файла. Есть виртуальный метод `getStringData()`в который я заношу данные с разделителем `;` и записываю их в таблицу `.csv`, и есть несколько переопределенных конструкторов в которые я передаю параметры из `getStringData()`

```
public string getStringData()
{
    string str = "1";
    str = str.ToString();
    str += ";";
    str += itemCount.ToString();
    str += ";";
    str += itemPrice.ToString();
    str += ";";
    return str;
}

public  Furniture(string str)
{
    str = str.Substring(2);
    string name = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(";"));
    this.itemName = name;
    str = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(";") + 1);
    itemPrice = int.Parse(str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(";")));
    str = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(";") + 1);
    itemCount = int.Parse(str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(";")));
}
```

Тут происходит считывание из файла

```
public void LoadData()
{
    string path = @"C:\Desktop\examples.csv";
    FileStream fstream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fstream, Encoding.UTF8);

    while(!sr.EndOfStream)
    {

        string str = getStringData();

        if(str.Length > 0)
        {
            Item itm = null;

            switch(Int32.Parse(str.Substring(0,1)))
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        itm = new Furniture(str);
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        itm = new Clothes(str);
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        itm = new HouseholdAppliance(str);
                        break;
                    }
                case 4:
                    {
                        itm = new Clothes(str);
                        break;
                    }
            }
           str = sr.ReadToEnd();
           Console.WriteLine(str); 
        }
    }
}
```

Укажите как сделать правильно

Comment: Вот список CSV-парсеров: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2081418/276994

Comment: а почему нельзя сделать это стандартными средствами через streamreader?

Comment: Потому что csv — не такой простой формат. Чтобы правильно разбить строку на части, вам понадобится, например, сканировать кавычки (пример: `"x y","x+y","x,y","x\"y"`).

Comment: @VladD, в csv вроде кавычки дублированием экранируются, а не обратным слешем

Comment: @Grundy: Вот именно поэтому, чтобы не кодировать и не держать в голове все эти тонкости, и нужен готовый парсер :)

Comment: @VladD, как я понимаю это единственная тонкость с этим форматом :)

Comment: @Grundy: Ещё Split по запятой не работает, если есть строки с запятой в кавычках.

Comment: @VladD, ну так это ж как раз к тонкости со строками и относится :)

Comment: @Grundy: Ну да. А ещё как-то кодируется `\n` (не знаю, как точно).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40209/discussion-between-grundy-and-vladd).

Answer (score 1):

Надо было просто без `FiltStream` делать считывание

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.UTF8);

while(!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    string str = getStringData();

    str = sr.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Формировать строку проще шаблоном:

```
public string GetStringData()
{
    return string.Format("1;{0};{1};", itemCount, itemPrice);
}
```

Парсить по разделителю стандартным методом:

```
public void Furniture(string str)
{
    string[] strParse = str.Split(';');
    string name = strParse[0];
    itemPrice = int.Parse(strParse[1]);
    itemCount = int.Parse(strParse[2]);
}

public void LoadData()
{
    string path = @"C:\Desktop\examples.csv";
    FileStream fstream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fstream, Encoding.UTF8);

    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string str = getStringData();

        if (str.Length > 0)
        {
            Item itm = null;

            switch (Int32.Parse(str[0]))
            {
                case 1:
                {
                     itm = new Furniture(str);
                     break;
                 }
            }
            str = sr.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, чет у меня много лишнего было в коде